# Set of real symmetric matrices with signature $(2,1)$ is open

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $S$ be the space of all $3\times 3$ real symmetric matrices, let $B$ be the subset of $S$ with signature $(2,1,0)$. Show that $B$ is open in $S$ in the topology of $\mathbb{R}^6$.

My thoughts: since all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional vector spaces, we use the operator topology on $S$ instead. For any matrix $A\in B$, let $\delta$ be the smallest absolute value of the eigenvalues of $A$. Then if $\|A-C\|<\delta$ in the operator norm, I feel that $C$ will not have its eigenvalues deviate from $A$ too much, therefore maintaining the same signature.

Is it correct, and how to prove my last statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A corrected solution, using the characteristic polynomial:

For any $A\in S$, all zeros of the characteristic polynomial $f_A$ are real. Assume $A\in B$, so $f_A$ has two positive zeros (or one double zero) and one negative zero. If $A'\in S$ is close enough to $A$, then $f_{A'}$ is close to $f_A$, and since all zeros of $f_{A'}$ are real, their signs must be identical to those of the zeros of $f_A$. Thus $A'$ has the same signature.

Comment: Well, I don't want to be hyper-critical, but at least you need to use that $f_{A'}$ has still 3 real roots. Ok, it has. But can you prove such general statement about real polynomials with all roots real? Maybe there is a simple argument I don't see...

Comment: Ok, I have found it here. But they need some complex analysis for the proof. http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~alen/articles/polyroots.pdf

Comment: Let's try. Let $f$ be a monic polynomial with all 3 roots real, one negative, and two positive. Let $a$ be the negative root, so the derivative $f'$ is positive on a neighborhood of $a$, and $f$ is bounded from below on $[a+\epsilon,0]$. Under small perturbations, no new roots can appear inside $[a+\epsilon,0]$, and the derivative remains positive near $a$, thus the number of negative roots remain $1$.

Comment: Of course, for similar reasons, no new roots can appear inside $(-\infty,a-\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your argument might be formalized but the following argument is simpler. Find a basis in which the form has matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1,1,-1)$. Then under sufficiently small perturbations, the "upper-left" subdeterminants $D_1, D_2, D_3$ will be positive, positive, negative.

Comment: What is the upper-left subdeterminants?

Comment: The subdeterminand of a matrix consisting of first $k$ raws and first $k$ columns. You might look at this text: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_law

Comment: If you are not familiar with the "sub-determinant rule", you can argue as follow: the span of the "positive" eigenvectors $v_1, v_2$ is a 2 dimensional subspace on which $A$ is positive-definite -- this remains invariant under small perturbations (this should be easy). For the third vector $w$, $(Aw,w)$ is negative and so is $(\tilde{A}w,w)$ for a small perturbation $\tilde{A}$ of $A$. So, $\tilde{A}$ is regular, positive-definite on a 2D subspace and is not positive-definite on whole $\mathbb{R}^3$. There only possible signature is then $(2,1)$.